# How do I save a token issued by a 3rd party?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

**Scenario:**

I am following the OAuth 2 flow in order to obtain an access token. Everything works fine using Fiddler. I am redirected to the 3rd party login screen, where if I click approve, I see a code appended to the url as a querystring. How do I store this code in my application?

**Summary:**

I get the code from a live website and now I need to use it in my application in order to get the access token using this code. How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ps. I am using Web Api.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The solution was to give the provider a callback URL which they will call once the user has approved to share their data with our company after logging in via the provider's login interface.

I set up a GET in my WEB API controller such that when the provider hits our GET, we get the code and now we can use that to continue the rest of the OAuth flow, e.g. obtaining an access token.